# Repeating Menu but only repeats once

Tags: python

Whenever I select option 1 to play the game, the menu resets itself and starts from the beginning. It only does this once however and on the second time, choosing option 1 starts the game.
When I select any other option, it runs on the first attempt and does not repeat. Any help to stop this?

```
#Jake Eaton
#Menu

import time
from typing import type, type2
from main_game import Main_Game                                                     #Imports time, system and name Modules
from view_leaderboard import View_LB                                                #Imports defined code with the names type, type 2, Main_Game and View_LB
from os import system, name

def clear():
    if name =='nt':                                                                 #Defines the clear command for the Terminal
        _ = system('cls')

type("Welcome\n")
time.sleep(2)
type("Welcome to the only Text Adventure you will ever need to play in order to learn!\n")
time.sleep(2)
type("This Text Adventure covers the AQA A-level Computer Science Topic 4.6\n")
time.sleep(2)
type("Please remember that this is still in Beta and may never have a full 1.0 release\n")
time.sleep(2)
type("All releases and the source code can be found on Github using the link: https://github.com/Spud-Lord/Mock-NEA\n")
time.sleep(2)
type("To view the releases, just click on the releases tab on the Github Page\n")
time.sleep(2)
type("So let us begin!")
time.sleep(2)


type("Now then...")
time.sleep(2)
type("What do you want to do? Just type in the number of the option you want!")
time.sleep(2)
def Main_Menu():                                                                    #Defines all indented code as Main_Menu
    menu = input("""
[1] - Start Game!
[2] - View Leaderboard  
[3] - Exit Game

""")                                                                                #The triple speech marks allow the Menu to go over multiple lines with only one code

    if menu == "1":
        clear()                                                                     #Calls Clear Definition to clear Terminal Screen
        Main_Game()

    elif menu == "2":
        print("")
        View_LB()                                                                   #Calls View_LB Definition to view leaderboard
        time.sleep(2)
        print("")
        Main_Menu()

    elif menu == "3":
        exit()                                                                      #Exits the game

    else:
        type("Please type in one of the numbers above...\n")
        Main_Menu()                                                                 #Loops back round if the user doesn't enter one of the numbers
        
Main_Menu()                                                                         #Allows the Menu to loop
```

Comment: Try calling `Main_Menu()` again after calling `Main_Game()` - like you do in all the other branches of that `if`.

Comment: No that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I **did not** reproduce your issue with the following code.
It seems you at least need to replace `type(...)` by `print` though!

The code needs to be cleaned up so that it becomes more readable. Put all your functions first then add the main part of the code (which starts at `print("Welcome\n")`)

```
#Jake Eaton
#Menu

import time

#from main_game import Main_Game                                                     #Imports time, system and name Modules
#from view_leaderboard import View_LB                                                #Imports defined code with the names print, print 2, Main_Game and View_LB
from os import system, name

def clear():
    if name =='nt':                                                                 #Defines the clear command for the Terminal
        _ = system('cls')

print("Welcome\n")
time.sleep(2)
print("Welcome to the only Text Adventure you will ever need to play in order to learn!\n")
time.sleep(2)
print("This Text Adventure covers the AQA A-level Computer Science Topic 4.6\n")
time.sleep(2)
print("Please remember that this is still in Beta and may never have a full 1.0 release\n")
time.sleep(2)
print("All releases and the source code can be found on Github using the link: https://github.com/Spud-Lord/Mock-NEA\n")
time.sleep(2)
print("To view the releases, just click on the releases tab on the Github Page\n")
time.sleep(2)
print("So let us begin!")
time.sleep(2)


print("Now then...")
time.sleep(2)
print("What do you want to do? Just print in the number of the option you want!")
time.sleep(2)
def Main_Game():
    print ("Main game")

def View_LB():
    print ("LB")

    
def Main_Menu():                                                                    #Defines all indented code as Main_Menu
    menu = input("""
[1] - Start Game!
[2] - View Leaderboard  
[3] - Exit Game

""")                                                                                #The triple speech marks allow the Menu to go over multiple lines with only one code

    if menu == "1":
        clear()                                                                     #Calls Clear Definition to clear Terminal Screen
        Main_Game()

    elif menu == "2":
        print("")
        View_LB()                                                                   #Calls View_LB Definition to view leaderboard
        time.sleep(2)
        print("")
        Main_Menu()

    elif menu == "3":
        exit()                                                                      #Exits the game

    else:
        print("Please print in one of the numbers above...\n")
        Main_Menu()                                                                 #Loops back round if the user doesn't enter one of the numbers
        
Main_Menu()
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I replaced the prints with what I wanted it to actually do rather than the prints and it didn't work. While the prints were there it did work! But I want it to actually run the code in the function which is in a separate program